# How to show the logical equivalence of the following two definitions of continuity in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> **Definition 1.** Let $(X,\mathfrak{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{T}_Y)$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$. Then we will say that $f$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for all $\{f(x)\}\subseteq V\in \mathfrak{T}_y$ there exists $\{x\}\subseteq U\in\mathfrak{T}_X$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $(X,\mathfrak{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{T}_Y)$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$. Then we will say that $f$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for all $\{f(x)\}\subseteq V\in \mathfrak{T}_y$  we have $ f^{-1}(V)\in\mathfrak{T}_X$.

The problem is to prove that Def. 1 and Def 2. are logically equivalent **without using the concept of [bases](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcquHo1MfMAhUDS44KHdPGCXwQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBase_(topology)&usg=AFQjCNEwDk1S3U9HKDCrUg89BkB8MGL-Gg&bvm=bv.121421273,d.c2E), only using the concept of open sets and their properties**.

Showing that Def. 2 implies Def. 1 is trivial. But I can't prove that Def. 1 implies Def. 2. I initially wanted to consider the following family of sets, $$S_x:=\{U:(x\in U)\land (U\subseteq f^{-1}(V))\land (U\in\mathfrak{T}_X)\}$$ for all $x\in X$. I wanted to prove that, $$\Psi=\bigcup_{x\in X}\left(\bigcup_{U\in S_x}U\right)=f^{-1}(V)$$but,

- I can't prove that $S_x$ will be non-empty for all $x\in X$
- Assuming that $S_x\ne\emptyset$ it can be shown that $\Psi\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$ but I can't prove that equality holds.

Can anyone help?

Comment: By the way, why do you (or the text) always write $\{a\}\subseteq B$ instead of simply $a\in B$?

Comment: The “there exists” in Definition 2 does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions are not equivalent.
Consider $X=Y=\Bbb R$ with usual topology and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\in\Bbb Q\\x&x\notin \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is definition-1-continuous at $0$: For every open set $V\ni 0$, we can let $U=V$ and find that $f(U)\subseteq V$.
But $f$ is not definition-2-continuous at $0$: Let $V=(-1,1)$. Then $f^{-1}(V)=\Bbb Q\cup(-1,1)$, which is not open.